# Find fixed subfield $\mathbb{C}(x_1, ..., x_n)$ for some $\langle\tau\rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

I have a $\langle\tau\rangle_n$:
$\tau(x_i)$ = $x_{i+1}$, $i = 1,...,n$
$\tau(x_n)$ = $x_1$
So, I need find for $\mathbb{C}(x_1, ..., x_n)_{\langle\tau\rangle}$ fixed subfield, but I have no ideas how can I do this. Maybe I need to check that any point from $\mathbb{C}(x_1, ..., x_n)$ is fixed point but how can I do this? And one more thought: my subfield is finite, so maybe I can use primitive element theorem?

Comment: For starters, try to find some fixed elements. One nice way to do this: if a group $G$ acts on a commutative ring $R$, then for any $r \in R$, every coefficient of the polynomial $\prod_{g \in G} (t - gr)$ is fixed by $G$ (exercise).

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I proved this statement and what does it follow?

Comment: Once you've found a bunch of fixed elements you can try proving (or disproving) that the subfield they generate is the entire fixed subfield.

Comment: @Qiaochu I'm not sure I got your hint. Won't doing that to the indeterminates here give us the elementary symmetric polynomials? But they give rise to a degree $n!$ extension whereas we are looking for a degree $n$ extension. By basic Galois theory (or Kummer theory!) this cyclic extension is a root extension, so I think we need another tool.

Comment: @Jyrki: yes, that's what you get if you act on the indeterminates, but you can act on other polynomials too. Anyway, the comments above weren't intended to lead to a particular solution, they were intended to be general-purpose things to try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\zeta=e^{2\pi i/n}$.

To make notation simpler I will index your variables with $0,1,2,\ldots,n-1$ instead of the range from $1$ to $n$.

Consider the discrete Fourier transform of your vector of variables. That is, let
$$
y_k=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}x_j\zeta^{-kj}=x_0+\zeta^{-k}x_1+\zeta^{-2k}x_2+\cdots +\zeta^kx_{n-1}
$$
for all $k=0,1,2,\ldots,n-1$. The transformation $(x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1})\mapsto (y_0,y_1,\ldots,y_{n-1})$ is linear and invertible, so it follows that
$$
L:=\Bbb{C}(x_0,x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_{n-1})=\Bbb{C}(y_0,y_1,y_2,\ldots,y_{n-1}).
$$
Leaving the following to you:

- $\tau(y_k)=\zeta^ky_k$, for all $k=0,1,\ldots,n-1$.
- $y_0$ and $y_1^n$ are both fixed by $\tau$.
- For all $k=1,2,\ldots,n-2$ the element $\dfrac{y_{k+1}}{y_1y_k}$ is fixed by $\tau$.
- If we let $K=\Bbb{C}(y_0,y_1^n,y_{k+1}/(y_1y_k)\mid k=1,2,\ldots,n-2)$, then $K$ is fixed by $\tau$.
- $L=K(y_1)$ and $[L:K]\le n$.
- $K$ is the fixed field of $\tau$ and $[L:K]=n$.

Comment: I guess it is worth pointing out that by Kummer theory a cyclic extension of degree $n$ (of a field containing the prescribed roots of unity) is gotten by adjoining the $n$th root of a suitable element. We see this here also: $y_1^n\in K$, $L=K(y_1)$.

Comment: If you find the DFT a bit difficult to grok you can first do the case $n=2$. Then $y_0=x_0+x_1$, $y_1=x_0-x_1$ and the fixed field is $\Bbb{C}(y_0,y_1^2)$.

Comment: Very nice! You could have also used the invariants $y_k \cdot y_1^{n-k}$ that are polynomial.   I wonder what  a system of generators for the ring of polynomial invariants would be ( yes, they are not unique, so perhaps the Hilbert series would do).